# Javascript not beeing called

Tags: javascript, laravel

Maybe I missed a very important step, but I am trying to implement a simple calendar using laravel.
My JavaScript is not called. I could also make sure in a different table that the data coming from the controller is not empty. already dd it and checked.

Following is my code. I have no error in the browser. nothing in the alert or console.log too. 
I will appreciate your help to get this running.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<h3 class="page-title">@lang('Test calendar Appointement')</h3>
<div id='calendar'></div>
@stop
@section('javascript')
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
            alert("here");
            console.log("here");
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                // put your options and callbacks here
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                events : [
                @foreach($appointments as $appointment)
                {
                    title : '{{ $appointment->user->first_name . ' ' . $appointment->user->last_name }}',
                    start : '{{ $appointment->start_time }}',
                    @if ($appointment->finish_time)
                    end: '{{ $appointment->finish_time }}',
                    @endif

                },
                @endforeach
                ]
            })
        });
    </script>
    @endsection
```

Comment: So in your `layouts/app.blade.php` you have a `content` yield and a `javascript` yield? From Laravel 5 onwards `@stop` directive is not even mention in the documentation, so I would suggest to use `@endsection` instead. BTW I use `@stack('javascript')` at the end of the body tag on `layouts/app.blade.php` and `@push('scripts') <script> ... </script> @endpush` on the child templates. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#stacks

Comment: Thank you very much. I Change to the @endsection and also add @stack('javascript') and update a bit the event. Every thing work well now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your javascript code is working fine check below snippet but 
you have another issue in your code maybe the issue is in generating event

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
            alert("here");
            console.log("here");
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                // put your options and callbacks here
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                events : [    ]
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed I had two problems. the first was as  porloscerros suggested and the second one undefined variable in the event. I correct and everything work well now

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code looks good. I suspect there is a problem with you loop in the javacript. I recommend you do the loop in your controller and just pass a variable to the javacript. Also make sure you format your data well just like the javascript is expecting it.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
            alert("here");
            console.log("here");
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
             // put your options and callbacks here
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                events : [{{$myrecords_from_my_view}}]
            })
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the above suggestion and everything works now